# How can I call the next step execution if WizardForm.NextButton is disabled?

Tags: inno-setup

I have created my own "Next" button. So I need to emulate the original "Next" button click in order to proceed to the other installer steps.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inno Setup: Multiple Next Buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021265/inno-setup-multiple-next-buttons)

Answer (score 1):

```
Wizardform.NextButton.OnClick(nil)
```