# Inno Setup: Multiple Next Buttons

Tags: button, inno-setup, wizard

I want to have two buttons in my installer screen, both should end up taking the user to the next screen but each performs it's own side-logic.  Is it possible to have two NextButtons that both take you to the next screen but execute different code? Failing that, is there a way how to call WizardForm.NextButton programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick(WizardForm.NextButton);
```

Answer (score 1):

Keith, from a usability perspective, have you considered one next button and two radio buttons instead? The user selects the desired side logic via the radio buttons and then proceeds by clicking the next button. The radio button for the default side logic can already be pre-selected so most of the time the user just clicks next. This is at least how I would expect an Installer to behave if I was installing software.

Comment: Yes I did and I completely agree with what you are saying from a UX point of view. Having said that I wanted to investigate whether it is possible to do such a thing and it seems that calling NextButton.OnClick as indicated by @Miral works.